# Referencing variables in a constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm new to C++, and I had a question about constructors. Say, for example, I'm writing a class for a 2D vector. I want my constructor to take an `x` coordinate and a `y` coordinate. The issue is that I also have fields called `x` and `y` to store the coordinates.

If I'm writing this constructor in Java, for example, I would write:

```java
public class TwoDVector {
  int x;
  int y;

  public TwoDVector(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

Now, say I wanted to do something similar in C++. C++ doesn't seem to have a `this` keyword that works the same way as Java's, so would the only course of action be renaming the parameters? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: `this` is a pointer: `TwoDVector(int x, int y) { this->x = x; this->y = y; }` or *better*, using the initialization list: `TwoDVector(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) { }` .

Comment: `this` in C++ is a pointer. You can access a member through a pointer using the `->` operator. Example : `this->x = 10;`.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor

Comment: Also, there's no reason why you have to have parameter names the same as the member names.

Comment: Often people would name the parameters x_ and y_ instead of x and y, to avoid confusion.